# Large workbook slow to open, but fast when split into two linked workbooks. Why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel model where the main element is a single, large structured table which contains approx 2000 columns and 200 rows. Each column contains  a formula that is the same for each row. As an XLSB file, the workbook is about 11MB and takes 45 seconds to open. The formulas themselves are efficient -- a full calculation of the workbook is done in under 1 second.

If I split this model into two, using two seperate sheets in the same workbook (with references between them), performance does not change. But, when I split these sheets into two workbooks, with the links as external references, I can open both files and refresh links in about 10 seconds.

Why would seperate workbooks improve performance? Can the same performance be achieved within a single workbook?

EDIT: Sanitized workbooks can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz0YVEO1u0jOaGtpS1ZnR3kzRWc?usp=sharing
Model1.xlsb and Model2.xlsb are the split files. To create Model1and2.xlsb, all I did was move the two sheets from Model2 into Model1.

EDIT 2: Setting `Workbook.ForceFullCalculation=TRUE` resolves this issue. It definitely has something to do with time to load the dependency tree. I have added Model1and2-ForceFullCalculation.xlsb to the shared folder to demonstrate.

Comment: This is an intriguing question.  However, as-is, it's kind of hypothetical and you may just attract speculative answers.  Is the actual spreadsheet something you can share (possibly after sanitizing), so people can analyze what might be going on?  You could stick it at a public sharing site and post a link to it.

Comment: Good point @fixer1234 -- I'll do some obfuscation and sanitizing and post workbooks shortly

Comment: @fixer1234 Sorry, that took longer to scrub than I expected! Updated issue with link to download files.

Comment: I mainly use LO Calc.  It's supposed to be able to open these files but the two single files opened in recovery mode.  When they did  open, they were both a wall of error codes.  The combined file wouldn't open at all.  That just hung and had to be terminated.  So I can't directly test your symptom.  However, just the fact that the combined one behaved differently indicates that there's more going on than just splitting a file.  It's possible that the original file became corrupted, but it's something Excel is able to deal with, given a little extra time for internal cleanup.  (cont'd)

Comment: Try creating a new file the same way you did with the pieces, but do it with the whole thing.  That action may have left the corruption behind for the pieces, and it may give you a clean combined file.  Retest with that one and see what happens.

Comment: I'm hesitant to go down that path arbitrarily, as due to its complexity I believe it to be several days worth of effort to rebuild this model in a fresh workbook. Perhaps a last-ditch effort... I am almost certain that this has everything to do with the calculation dependencies. I saved a copy of this workbook with the Workbook.ForceFullCalculation property enabled (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-forcefullcalculation-property-excel). This opens instantly. I added it to the shared folder if you want to try.

Comment: I wasn't referring to rebuilding it, just copying the entire worksheet and pasting it into a new workbook.  Sometime the workbook "infrastructure" gets corrupted, and this replaces it with a fresh template.  It's usually a fast way to rule out that type of corruption.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. In that case, no, I have tried this and continue to have the same issue.